# Looping through Multiple CSV files and producing Multiple Outputs

Tags: python, loops, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am writing some python script that opens a .csv file, defines the dataframe, run some analysis (e.g. aggregate data, splitting columns, finding averages etc..) and plot the output of the analysis on a graph. The outputs will be both a graph (.png file) AND a csv file with the word "_ANALYSIS" added to the original file name at the end.

I have set it up as a loop function in Jupyter Notebook:

```
#import multiple csv files

import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pytz import all_timezones
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = glob.glob('folder/*.csv')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    #START OF THE ANALYSIS
    #Multiple lines of code starts here


    #GRAPH some outputs from the analysis
    df2 = df.replace(0, np.nan)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df2.groupby('Day_type').plot(x = 'Time', y = 'avg_vt', ax=ax, grid=True)


    #OUTPUT FILES: graph + csv file
    plt.savefig('*.png', index = False)
    file_name="file"+str(i+1)+"_ANALYSIS"
    df.to_csv('file1_ANALYSIS.csv', index = False)
```

Unfortunately, it isn't producing any outputs. There is no problem with the analysis code itself as I tried it before I added the loop function.

Thanks, 
R

Comment: the filename of `df.to_csv` is a static string, so it will be overwritten after every loop. And so is `plt.savefig('*.pnmg')`

Answer (score 2):

slightly more elegant with pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path

folder="C:\Users\Renaldo.Moonu\Desktop\folder name"
for file in Path(folder).glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df.groupby('Day_type').plot(x = 'Time', y = 'avg_vt', ax=ax, grid=True)

    plt.savefig(file.with_suffix('.png'), index = False)
    df.to_csv(file.with_suffix('.csv'), index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Would this sit right at the top? I'm guessing that the 4th line `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` would be placed after the `#GRAPH some outputs from the analysis` ...

Comment: it would replace your loop. Also; `df.fillna` replaces the line `df.replace(0, np.nan)`

Comment: Great! quick question: Would `Path(folder)`  be replaced by `"C:\Users\Renaldo.Moonu\Desktop\folder name"` ?

Comment: Ah, you should declare the variable `folder="C:\Users\Renaldo.Moonu\Desktop\folder name"` first

Comment: so it'll look like this: `folder ="C:\Users\Renaldo.Moonu\Desktop\SSP3\SomeFolder"
for file in Path(folder).glob('*.csv'):` ?